# Remove wwwroot from module definition in typescript generated javascript, ie define("wwwroot/services/

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, tsc

Using Asp.Net Core 1.0 and Typescript 2.0 I am attempting to concatenate all generated javascript to a single file (site.js) at the root of wwwroot.  My directory structure is:

```
Site
--wwwroot\
----site.js
--typings\
--tsconfig.json
```

I've looked over the tsconfig.json [schema docs](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig).  I've played with different combinations of "sourceRoot", "rootDir", "mapRoot" and "ourDir" but can't quite seem to figure out the right combination.  Using "outDir" seems to cause it to ignore every file in my project and only list the following file in the tsc output:

```
C:/Users/shawn/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
```

The generated module definitions come out like

```
define("wwwroot/services/MessengerService"
```

and I would like them to come out as

```
define("services/MessengerService"
```

because asp.net core serves from wwwroot.  Full tsconfig.json below:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "listFiles": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",

    "sourceRoot": "wwwroot",
    "rootDir": "./wwwroot",
    "mapRoot": "wwwroot",

    "outFile": "wwwroot/site.js",


    "baseUrl": "wwwroot",
    "paths": {
      "file-drop": [ "typings/file-drop.d.ts" ]


    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/ref",
    "wwwroot/lib",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/812) type script issue the outDir is automatically excluded from sources, which makes a certain amount of sense, I just wish there had been some sort of warning.  The wwwroot in the define issue stemmed from using triple slash references to the typings directory

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/moment.d.ts" />
```

Which was causing the calculated common root.Switching the outDir to wwwroot/scripts and removing all triple slash references generated the

```
define("services/MessengerService"
```

output I was looking for.